# Update table based on a time range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way I could update based on a date range in a postgres DB?

Meaning if I have a row with following values,

```
name code some_timestamp
abc  1    2020-09-07T13:22:23.206862
```

I want to update the row base on the *name* and *some_timestamp* fields.

I could do the following and it works.

```
UPDATE myTable SET code=2 WHERE name='apple' and some_timestamp='2020-09-07T13:22:23.206862';
```

But I do not want to target the specific datetime and instead be able to update as long as the

name matches and date range falls within the same day.

Is there a way to achieve this? Tried via *date_trunc*. No errors but it doesn't perform the update. (Tried with *LIKE* too and same outcome).

```
update myTable set code=1 where name='apple' and some_timestamp=date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2020-09-07T13:22:23.206862');
```

Otherwise achievable via the *BETWEEN* key but trying to see if this can be done via *date_trunc*. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You have it backwards . You need to apply the `date_trunc` to `some_timestamp` and compare that to a date: `date_trunc('day', some_timestamp) =  '2020-09-07'::date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
update myTable
    set code=1
    where name = 'apple' and 
          some_timestamp >= date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2020-09-07T13:22:23.206862') and
          some_timestamp < date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2020-09-07T13:22:23.206862') + interval '1 day';
```

You can also use:

```
update myTable
    set code=1
    where name = 'apple' and 
          date_trunc('day', some_timestamp) = date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2020-09-07T13:22:23.206862');
```

But this is not as index-friendly.

Comment: It works! Finding the 2nd more readable but now in a dilemma cos option 1 seems to be more performant like you mentioned.. This table on average holds about 5 mil records.

Comment: @karvai . . . You can always add an index on `name, date_trunc('day', some_timestamp), timestamp)`, if you often use the day portion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_trunc()` on both sides:

```
update myTable 
   set code=1 
 where name='apple' 
   and date_trunc('day', some_timestamp) =
         date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP '2020-09-07T13:22:23.206862');
```